# Why is one class method absent from its object file when others are present?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

This is likely a silly mistake, but I haven't been able to fix it.

In: https://github.com/jlettvin/Greased-Grep files: gg_state.h / gg_state.cpp The "follow" method is absent from gg_state.o

```
$ nm gg_state.o|grep follow
```

while the "load" method above it

```
$ nm gg_state.o|grep load
```

is present.  By visual inspection, the follow method should appear in gg_state.o.

Temporarily, the code for follow is duplicated in gg.cpp and compiles there, but it belongs in gg_state.cpp.  The code implementing the method is at the end of both files and is identical.  Compilation doesn't fail with duplicate definitions which is a second indicator that the compiler is ignoring just the code for follow in gg_state.cpp.

The original name for the method was search, and the name was changed to follow to avoid possible conflict with c++ regex.

The program executes properly because gg.cpp has the code it needs but this method should appear in gg_state.o.

This app compiles on ubuntu linux 16.04 using g++ 7.1.0 --std=c++17 and requires experimental/filesystem and fmt/printf.  Test framework is catch.hpp but tests are not robust yet.

Why would the follow method not appear in the output of nm?

Comment: Post code directly here. External links are discouraged.

Comment: "possible conflict with c++ regex" this makes no sense. What kind of conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void
    follow (void* a_pointer, auto a_bytecount, const char* a_label="");
```

The `auto` parameter means that this is an abbreviated function template. Support for such things outside of the Concepts TS is a GCC extension.

Since this is a function template, usual rules about where you can and can't put templates apply.